# How to print the sorted excel ( which is done using .sort_value() ) in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

grade = pd.read_excel('data1.xlsx')
Total=grade['Total(48)']

print(Total)

Total.sort_value()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, Please provide a **[Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (min-reprex)**, and show us what you want, what you're currently getting, or your current error message, and what you've tried so far, also see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also see [**How to write a perfect question**](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question)

Comment: Does `print(total.sort_values())` work?

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the dataframe by column name like `Total(48)` using [pandas sort_values method](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html#pandas-dataframe-sort-values).

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd

grade = pd.read_excel('data1.xlsx')
print("Grade before sorting")
print(grade)

grade = grade.sort_values(by=['Total(48)'])

print("Grade after sorting")
print(grade)
```

**Output:**

```
Grade before sorting
      Name  Total(48)
0   Shovon          5
1    arsho         89
2  Ahmedur        -54
3   Rahman         10
4      Sho          1
5     john          6
6      ken         87

Grade after sorting
      Name  Total(48)
2  Ahmedur        -54
4      Sho          1
0   Shovon          5
5     john          6
3   Rahman         10
6      ken         87
1    arsho         89
```

`data1.xlsx`:

[image: data]

**References:**

- [Documentation on sort_values method](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html#pandas-dataframe-sort-values)